# SSAS how to build up dynamic range dimension

Tags: dynamic, range, ssas, dimension

In current cube, I have a calculated measure of average investment dollars. Now I want to create a range dimension table dynamically based on different amount for every department. The table would be something looks like this:

Dim_DollarRange

```
ID    MinRange    MaxRange    Description
1        1         2            1-2             
2        3         5            3-5             
3        6         9            6-9            
4       10        14           10-14
```

So basically there are two questions:

```
1) How to set up dimension table based on measures in cube dynamically?
2) How to look up in range dimension in SSAS?
```

I'm new to SSAS, thx for any answers or tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

Use the views that feed the Data Source Views to check the related fact data in your source system and filter the resulting dimesion list accordingly.  If you do not have a set of views interfacing between your source and cube, you can perform the same within your queries directly, it is just not as clean.

I use this technique to limit long dimension lists to only used values, providing users that directly access the cube (with Excel etc) a precise list of used options within their filters / slicers.  It does have the downside of masking possible options from users reports until they are consumed i.e. you will not see Cancelled Orders = 0 until the first cancelled order triggers of its creation.

I am assuming that you want the data to be dynamic, not the creation of Dimenions i.e. you know you require Dimension A, B, C and they relate to Fact Y and Z.  If you truely want to dynamically create whole dimensions (dimension name, measure group relationships etc), I do not think this is possible.